# FirebaseCloudMessaging (http v1 apis) without Google Signin in flutter

Tags: flutter, oauth, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing PushNotifications using FCM.
I wanted to refresh OAuth 2.0 accessToken without Google Auth Crendentais.
Even when registering client ID on Google APIs, there was no client secret for the iOS Client. Can't users update access tokens for `OAuth 2.0` with Firebase Authentication?

I spent my day on this issue.